# jquery datetimepicker 24 hour time format

Tags: jquery-plugins

I am using datetimepicker.js to select date and time of jquery. How do i change the time format from 12 hour clock to 24 hour clock?????

Answer (score 19):

i got the answer.. You just need to mention "HH:mm" in the format for 24 hour clock or "hh:mm" for the 12 hour clock.

Comment: Thanks. Now I can breath.

Comment: The OP has answered his own question and I can confirm that on the Trent Richardson timepicker this worked for me: `timeFormat: 'HH:mm'` Also formats are defined here: https://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ I wasted a bit of time trying some of the newer replies below which led me to add this comment. Don't be me, save time and just use HH:mm

Answer (score 15):

Use the following time format: "HH:mm:ss".

```
$('#input_time').datetimepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    showSecond: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy", 
    timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"
});
```

Answer (score 8):

for 24 hour time format  with hour and minute follow this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#clockPicker').timepicker({
        'timeFormat':'H:i'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one :

```
$("#input").datetimepicker({
   format: 'hh:mm a'
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code to get date in dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM format using datetimepicker

For 24hour format use Capitalize letter like HH and for 12hour format use small letter like hh as given in below code snippet.

```
    $('#element').datetimepicker(
        {
            format: 'DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm A'
        }
    );
```

Please vote answer if you find it useful for you. I am sure you will get it useful.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this worked for me:

```
$("#input").datetimepicker({
   format: 'hh:ii'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(element).datetimepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
timeFormat: 'hh:mm TT',
showOn: "focus",
changeMonth: true,
changeYear: true
}).click(function () {
});
```

Comment: Hello :). Do you want to provide more information about your code? What it does and how it does that? That would make it easier to understand what you did. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way:

```
$("#input").datetimepicker({
   format: 'hh:i'
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Found it! Thanx to this post http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/2566 . The info there is not very correct. The right format for the time is 'H:i:s'. Like in the good old PHP put put the letters only once. I do not have solution for the date but I think that it will works in the same way. Hope this help.