# Displaying 24 hours clock on bootstrap datetimepicker 3

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker

Do you know how to display a 24 hours clock on bootsrap datetimepicker?

Here is my code, I already set the months in french, I just can't set the clock how I want to :

```
$('#qsdfqsf').daterangepicker({
timePicker         : true,
timePickerIncrement: 1,
use24hours:true,
"locale": {
    "separator": " - ",
    "applyLabel": "Appliquer",
    "cancelLabel": "Annuler",
    "fromLabel": "Du",
    "toLabel": "Au",
    "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
    "daysOfWeek": [
        "Di",
        "Lu",
        "Ma",
        "Me",
        "Je",
        "Ve",
        "Sa"
    ],
    "monthNames": [
        "Janvier",
        "Février",
        "Mars",
        "Avril",
        "Mai",
        "Juin",
        "Juillet",
        "Août",
        "Septembre",
        "Octobre",
        "Novembre",
        "Decembre"
    ],
    "firstDay": 1,
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm',
}
})
```

Comment: Try using 'HH:mm' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809883/jquery-datetimepicker-24-hour-time-format/14243448

Comment: It doesn't work, do you have any other idea?